# How can I resize a system partition?

Tags: partitioning

I installed Ubuntu on my HDD. The system created 2 partitions, one sda1 for GRUB and second sda2 for the system itself. The partition with the system has over 900GBi, and I would like to make it smaller as I need some space for another OS.

Is there any way to make this sda2 partition with Ubuntu OS smaller, even though there is already an operating system installed on it?

[image: GPARTED screen]

Comment: Show us a screenshot from `gparted` of your partition layout, please.  Or, open the terminal, run `sudo fdisk -l` and then provide us that output as an edit to our question.

Comment: I added it as a link to my original question.

Comment: Do you still have the installation disk you used?  You cannot resize your root partition while you're logged into the on-disk installation, you'd need the LIveCD / LiveUSB to properly resize the partition downwards.

Comment: Yes, i have. So i should boot Ubuntu from USB, and then use the gparted again ?

Comment: Yes, and shrink the partition you want to shrink from gparted within the USB drive instead of booting to the computer's install itself.

Comment: Yes, that is how I meant it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- right-click on /dev/sda2 and select **resize**
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda2 as far left as you wish to create unallocated space
- click the Apply checkmark icon
- reboot the computer